# Meaning of a phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning

Please what is the meaning of this phrase:"Besides what you can do to me".
What is the difference between saying to me or for me?

Answer (score 3):

'what you can do to me' could be good or bad. For example, upset me, or make my heart beat fast because I love you (good suffering). But 'what you can do for me' is only good, like helping me.

Comment: Or it could be "shoot me" or "beat me up".

Comment: I think you'll be hard pressed to come up with many examples where "do to me" implies anything but harm.  I could be convinced by evidence, though.